# How do I integrate this PHP code into a Laravel 5.1 project?

Tags: php, laravel

I use Laravel 5.1 and need to integrate the following code into our project. Do I have to create a vendor package for this code or is there a faster way?

```
<?php
require 'be_ixf_client.php';
use BrightEdge\BEIXFClient;

$be_ixf_config = array(
BEIXFClient::$ACCOUNT_ID_CONFIG => "0000000000000",  
BEIXFClient::$CANONICAL_PROTOCOL_CONFIG  => "https"
);
$be_ixf = new BEIXFClient($be_ixf_config);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php
print $be_ixf->getHeadOpen(); 
?>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
print $be_ixf->getBodyOpen(); 
print $be_ixf->close(); 
?>
<div>Header</div>
<div>Body</div>
<div class="be-ix-link-block"><!--Link Equity Target Div--></div>
<div>Footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you should be posting your account id

Comment: I removed the account number. Thanks for catching this.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I assume the code you are using is this: https://github.com/sammyyu/be_ixf_php_sdk so the best practice would be requiring it with composer like: `composer require brightedge/be_ixf_php_sdk`

Comment: That's the first step, but OP's gonna have to do more than just that.